# Display page url SharePoint xslt

Tags: xslt, sharepoint-2010

I was following this link
http://spyralout.com/2009/03/16/current-page-url-using-xsl-for-content-query-web-part/

I want to display query string value on my page. For that I have seen one solution on stackoverflow which I found bit complicated.So my approach is :

1) Get the current url

2) Use substring-after on that url to get the value of query string..

I can explain this with some e.g..

My Page url is www.stackoverflow.com/questions.aspx?display=18..I want to display 18 on my page...

What I have done so far...

1)I have added namespace in my xslt
xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime"

2) Added a parameter

`<xsl:param name=”PageUrl” />`

3)Added this value in variable

`<xsl:variable name=”DetailPageLink” select=”$PageUrl” />`

4) Now when I am trying to use this in substring-after, its not displaying any value...?

`<xsl:value-of select="substring-after($DetailPageLink,'=')" />`

5) I have also tried

`<xsl:value-of select="$DetailPageLink" />`  but its not giving any value..?

Any idea where I am going wrong...

Thanks again Dimitre for answering it...but still the problem is same...as I said I don't want to pass url into global parameter..I want it to be dynamic...to answer your questions ..I don't know the logic behind it...I think its because of this namespace what I have used....PageUrl gets the current page url....but when I am trying

xsl:copy-of select="$DetailPageLink"/> or

xsl:value-of select="$DetailPageLink" /> or

xsl:value-of select="substring-after($DetailPageLink,'=')" /> ...

Its not displaying any output...but interestingly its showing page url when I am using

a href="{$DetailPageLink}">Jack
/a>

So  that means PageUrl is getting the value ....otherwise a tag should not have shown any output...

If you know any other approach to get the current page url , please let me know....

Comment: So what is the question? It is highly desirable that you provide a complete (but short) example: the source XML document, the transformation, the rules governing the transformation, the wanted and the actual results and what is wrong with the actual result.

Comment: Sorry if it was not clear..There is no xml only thing..for e.g..If my page url is http://stackoverflow.com/questions.aspx?display=1....I want to display 1 on my webpart...so for that I want to use <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($DetailPageLink,'=')" /> but its not displaying anything...I tried normally <xsl:value-of select="$DetailPageLink" /> and I didn't get anything...

Comment: Once again, you must provide as much information that is relevant to the problem *within your question*. So far, you haven't done so and thus have a very minimal chance of someone with telepatic abilities to even try to help.

Comment: Thanks Dimitre for replying but You asked me few questions and I think I have tried to answer all of your questions..I have mentioned I am following above link so I dont want to paste everything but if thats what you want I am editing my original post....

Comment: No, I never recommend providing *long* XML documents and/or XSLT code. If you are unable to demonstrate the problem shortly, this often means that you don't understand the nature of the problem well and maybe there isn't any problem at all. Good questions contain simple and short data and code -- there are a lot such questions around -- just look and learn.

Comment: I don't think so you own Stackoverflow..? ...so if you want to help you are most welcome but please don't just comment anything and take out your frustration on my post just because you are having a bad day .....I have explained everything and I couldn't find it anywhere..

Comment: This is much better now. I hope you will always use this style in future questions. This also proves that my comments were not in vain :)

Comment: Notice to all readers. I initially voted to close this question as "not a real question" because it originally didn't contain essential information to even define the problem in an understandable way. Now. as result of my comments the OP has significantly improved this question and it has become a good one. Unfortunately, SO doesn't provide the functionality to cancel my close vote. Please, disregard my close vote when reading and reacting to this question.

Comment: @_Jack: After significantly improving this question, I have upvoted it -- +1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1)I have added namespace in my xslt
>   xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime"

This isn't necessary.

> 2) Added a parameter
>
> xsl:param name=”PageUrl” />
>
> 3)Added this value in variable
>
> `<xsl:variable name=”DetailPageLink” select=”$PageUrl” />`
>
> 4) Now when I am trying to use this in substring-after, its not
>   displaying any value...?
>
> `<xsl:value-of select="substring-after($DetailPageLink,'=')" />`
>
> 5) I have also tried
>
> `<xsl:value-of select="$DetailPageLink" />` but its not giving any
>   value..?
>
> Any idea where I am going wrong...

The facts above clearly show that the global parameter `$PageUrl` either isn't initialized or anyway, its string value is the empty string.

**Solution**:

**You need to set the global parameter `$PageUrl` with the appropriate string value** *before* initiating the transformation. You may also give it a default value in the `select` attribute of the global `xsl:param` and if the default value is picked this proves that the parameter wasn't initialized and passed by the initiator of the XSLT transformation/

**Below is correct XSLT code** that either uses the default value of `$PageUrl` or the value that is provided for this global parameter at the time of the initiation of the transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:param name="pPageUrl" select=
 "'www.stackoverflow.com/questions.aspx?display=18&amp;somethingElse=xyz'"/>

 <xsl:template match="/t">
  <xsl:variable name="vQSPart" select=
  "concat('&amp;', substring-after($pPageUrl,'?'),'&amp;')"/>

  <xsl:value-of select=
    "substring-before
        (substring-after($vQSPart, '&amp;display='),
         '&amp;')
    "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on any XML document (not used), the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
18
```

**When I set the value of the global parameter** *outside* **of the transformation** to: `'www.stackoverflow.com/questions.aspx?something=abcd&display=123&somethingElse=xyz'` and then again perform the transformation, I again get the correct result:

```
123
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Dimitre but I found one problem in your solution you have hard coded the url ...The reason I was using that approach is because I don't need to hard code the url.Here display=18  so it can be anything and thats why I want to write xslt so that I can get the value...The solution what I was trying it doesn't work but interestingly when you put it in <a> tag like this :<a href="{$DetailPageLink}">Jack</a> ..It shows my page url ...

Comment: @Jack: As I said (and not only said, but also verified), my solution works when the global param is set from outside -- look at the very end of my answer.

Comment: @Jack: In order to solve your problem, more data is needed. Please, put in your XSLT: "`<xsl:copy-of select="$DetailPageLink"/>`" and tell us what is output between the quotes.

Comment: @Jack: no, I don't see in your question the result of `"<xsl:copy-of select="$DetailPageLink"/>"`. Also, it is necessary to publish the code that sets the value of this parameter and then invokes the XSLT transformation -- the bug is within this code, which you havent shown to us.

Comment: The output of "xsl:copy-of select="$DetailPageLink"/>" is ""...(Blank)...DetailPagelink is a variable which is getting its value from global parameter....If you have any other working example which does the same thing, I will be happy to see it...

Comment: @Jack: This means at leat one of two things: 1).The global parameter was not set with the URL. 2).`$DetailPageLink` wasn't set to the value of the global parameter. I am beginning to think that the name of the global parameter isn't probably the one you think it is. Can you show the code that sets this global parameter and then initiates the transformation? Asking a second time for this...

Comment: Yes you are right but thats what the problem is :)....that its not doing what its supposed to do...and to yours question ..as I said before twice...:) I am not sure about the logic...I am referring to these links and I believe its because of that namespace...If you can find out some solution or the logic do let me know...http://whitepages.unlimitedviz.com/2011/01/using-xsl-to-get-the-url-of-the-current-sharepoint-page-for-the-content-query-web-part/ http://objectmix.com/sharepoint/297584-using-xsl-content-query-web-part-read-current-page-url.html

Comment: I appreciate your effort in trying to find some solution but I am sorry may be you came to know about this now...but I knew that ...and I guess all we have achieved in doing is extensively detailed problem.....This global parameter $PageUrl....people are using in sharepoint and there are several blogs....may be you are not aware of SharePoint....but I wanted some SharePoint guy to help me in this regard that why its not working.....if we are using it other than putting in a> tag....I would appreciate any other users to tell us the solution ....

Comment: @Jack: I agree. As we have concluded, the problem is not in the XSLT. Therefore, could you please, retag the question and remove the XSLT tag?

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that the parameter:

```
xsl:param name="PageUrl"
```

doesn't actually work on the web page. Even if you did add in the ParameterBinding line (as suggested above). It does *appear* to work in SP Designer, but when viewed through the browser, the PageUrl parameter returns an empty or Null value. The right parameter to use to return the current page URL is the ServerVariable one. So set up the ParemeterBinding like this (you'll need to add your own angle brackets as this website won't like it if I type them in):

```
ParameterBinding Name="PageAddr" Location="ServerVariable(URL)" DefaultValue=""/
```

The PageAddr is just a random name I'm assigning to the Parameter, which won't be confused with the PageUrl one. Next call the Parameter in the StyleSheet, like this:

```
xsl:param name="PageAddr" /
```

Now you can call the Parameter anywhere in your XSLT code using $PageAddr .

Be warned this Parameter doesn't work in SP Designer, but will work in the browser.

[Does anyone know why Microsoft thought having one Parameter work in SPD and another work in the browser was a good idea?]

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to display QueryString information is due a ParameterBinding:

In ParameterBindings add:

```
<ParameterBinding Name="subsiteLink" Location="ServerVariable(PATH_INFO)" DefaultValue=""/>
```

In XSL-stylesheet of DataView add:

```
<xsl:param name="subsiteLink"></xsl:param>
path_info: <xsl:value-of select="$subsiteLink"/><br/>
```

This is simplified way of displaying data.

Answer (score 0):

To initialize the Global Variable "PathUrl" you must:

1) Add the following line into ParameterBindings

```
<ParameterBinding Name="PageUrl" Location="ServerVariable(QUERY_STRING)" DefaultValue=""/>
```

2) Add the following line into the xsl:stylesheet after the ParameterBindings

```
<xsl:param name="PageUrl"></xsl:param>
```

3) now you can use the following line to show the URL parameters

```
<xsl:value-of select="$PageUrl"/>
```

for other server variables you can visit http://joshmccarty.com/2012/06/using-asp-net-servervariables-in-a-sharepoint-data-view-web-part/

Regards :)